# Wifi internet is not working in my ubuntu system

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, internet

I have installed Ubuntu in my system but when I am using Wi-Fi then after sometime the Wi-Fi internet is automatically shut down

When I check my wifi driver it shows me something like this

```
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 34
       serial: 10:0b:a9:50:b6:58
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.2.0-32-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 6000g2a-6.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:27 memory:e2d00000-e2d01fff
```

I also installed and checked the drivers for Ratal8821, still it did not work.

This problem is happening again and again whenever I turn on my system.
Can you tell me any solution to this?